# Extract substrings from a string with defined starting and ending points

Tags: python, regex, string, split, bioinformatics

I have a list of three sequences looking more or less like this (res):

```
res = [
     'NVAKMFPQRKFT<STOP>TVQTLMRNGTLLERG<STOP>CCEVSP',

     'QKRMDCNASV<STOP>TVTVQTLMQTL<STOP>TNTPKGG<STOP>',

     'MEKGYADAE<STOP>RKTF<STOP>MTVRAGCCGI<STOP>MK'
]
```

I want to split every one of these sequences into substrings that start with 'M' and end with (but do not include) < STOP >. These substrings are defined as exons here. I don't want my exons to overlap (the real sequences are much longer than in the sample here). And I want at least two characters in between M and < STOP >.

```
   exon = list()
   for seq in res:
        string = str(res)
        result = re.search("M(.*?)<STOP>", string)
        if result:
            found = list()
            found = result.group()
            exon.append(found)
   print exon
```

I want to get a nested list like this:

```
exon = [

     "['MFPQRKFT', 'MRNGTLLERG']",
     "['MDCNASV', 'MQTL']",
     "['MEKGYADAE', 'MTVRAGCCGI']"
]
```

But now I am only getting one list with a few exons, and I have < STOP > at the end of each of them.

Comment: When I hear "defined start and ending points", I read that as knowing integer indices; that's rather different from the actual use case.

Comment: BTW, could you please form your sample data as a real Python data structure? Right now it's not clear if it's a single big string that needs to be parsed, or a list of strings (but with no syntactic quotes provided), or something else. Part of the point of asking for a [mre] -- the shortest possible code that can be copied-and-pasted without changes to see the behavior the question surrounds -- is to avoid such ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capture group and re.findall that will return the value of the capture groups

```
(M.{2,}?)<STOP>
```

- `(` Capture **group 1** (This will be returned by re.findall)

  - `M.{2,}?` Match `M` and 2 or more times any char non greedy
- `)` Close group 1
- `<STOP>` Match literally

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/47QXaq/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rqdZyq)

If you only want to match uppercase chars (The `.` matches any char except a newline) you can use

```
(M[A-Z]{2,})<STOP>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dFW2Bw/1/)

For example

```
import re

exon = list()
res = [
     'NVAKMFPQRKFT<STOP>TVQTLMRNGTLLERG<STOP>CCEVSP',
     'QKRMDCNASV<STOP>TVTVQTLMQTL<STOP>TNTPKGG<STOP>',
     'MEKGYADAE<STOP>RKTF<STOP>MTVRAGCCGI<STOP>MK'
]

for seq in res:
    exon.append(re.findall(r"(M.{2,}?)<STOP>", seq))
    
print(exon)
```

Output

```
[
  ['MFPQRKFT', 'MRNGTLLERG'],
  ['MDCNASV', 'MQTL'],
  ['MEKGYADAE', 'MTVRAGCCGI']
]
```

Comment: Thank you, @The fourth bird. I appreciate you explaining what the pattern actually means/does!